# bootstrap 4 dual listbox plugin search is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-duallistbox

When i use filter option in bootstrap 4 dual listbox, if the 2 result appear and i select 2nd option automatically 1st option in added to list.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Dual-Select-Boxes-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Dual-Listbox/

Open above link and type Option 1 in 1st filter  list "Option 1" and "Option 10" will appear. click on "option 10" "option 1" will be added to list.

Answer (score 1):

Many users reported the same problem. Please refer the link

[github issue reference](https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox/issues/110)

You can try the solution in the below link

[solution](https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox/issues/110#issuecomment-280208531)

```
$(document).on('mouseover',"select",function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".filter").blur();
});
```